# Comparing member of a list in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a function (the long way) to test if a number I type in is in the list. I don't want to use the 'in' function. The question is why it only works when I type in numbers that are in the list and I get an error in line `if x == a[i]:` when a number is not in the list.

```
def is_member(x):

    a = [1,5,3,9,4,100]
    i = 0
    found = False

    while found == False:
        if x == a[i]:
            found = True
            break
        i += 1
    if found == True:
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
```

Comment: That is because when you are in the while loop, you do not check for the index of `i`. So `x == a[i]` also does the check for the element `a[i]` when the index i does not exist

Comment: You asked "Why do I get an error ?". Didn't you read the error message  : "IndexError: list index out of range" ?

Answer (score 2):

If there is no element in the list, then your `i` gets bigger and bigger until it becomes `i = len(a)`. At this point `a[i]` throws an `IndexError` since you went above the list size. Simple fix would be to use `while i < len(a):` instead of `while found == false:` since you break the loop at `x == a[i]` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are going outside the bounds of the list.

You should add a check so you can return when `i > len(a)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a for loop to avoid the index error, try this

```
def is_member(x):

    a = [1,5,3,9,4,100]

    for i in range(len(a)):
        if x == a[i]:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition that `if (i == len(a)-1): return False`.
Because the index can not exceed the length of list `a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_member(x):

    a = [1,5,3,9,4,100]
    i = 0
    found = False

    while found == False:
        if i >= len(a):
            return False # end of list reached
        if x == a[i]:
            found = True
            break
        i += 1
    if found == True:
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
```

to handle end of list, a piece of code has been added

In fact you do not another variable like `Found`, you can do it in below way.

```
def is_member(x):

    a = [1,5,3,9,4,100]
    i = 0

    while True:
        if i >= len(a):
            print 'test'
            return False # end of list reached
        if x == a[i]:
            return True
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
def is_member(x):
    a = [1,5,3,9,4,100]
    for i in a:
        if i == x:
            return "True"
    return "False"
```

Here we iterate over a, and if any member `== x` we return "True" right away.  If we have not returned by the end of the loop then the element is not present.